# Applying a background image to a td element in an email

Tags: css, outlook, newsletter

I have a `td` and want to put a `bg-image` in it. In know there are different problems with using newsletters with css on different clients.

I tried this:

```
<td style=" background-image: url('...absolute path...');
           background-repeat: repeat-y no-repeat;
           width: 15px;">&nbsp;
</td>
```

I tried also to add a class attribute to the `td` and putting the css in head.
Nothing works, the img does not appear.

EDIT:
Now I read from a German source that outlook does not support many css attributes like

- background-image
- background-position
- background-repeat
- display
- ﬂoat
- position

How can I add a background image to a `td` element?

Comment: I think you should only have one value for background-repeat.

Comment: Using one value, does not works, too. I even read, that for outlook, it is better to use two values, because the default value for x seems to be "repeat".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Full Width Backgrounds on Outlook '07/'10/'13](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280715/full-width-backgrounds-on-outlook-07-10-13)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that background image in css is supported in Outlook like that.

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Although tbf that site says 2003 does support it.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that the only way to put an image in a **td** is:

```
<td><img src"#" /></td>
```

Of course if you don't have other content than the image.